# Fill in missing elements of an array of date objects in PHP

Tags: php, date

I have an `array` of `objects` in `php` which looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
      (
        [day] => 1/23/2013
        [executions] => 1
      )

    [1] => Array
      (
        [day] => 1/24/2013
        [executions] => 1
      )

    [2] => Array
      (
        [day] => 1/27/2013
        [executions] => 10
      )

    [3] => Array
      (
        [day] => 1/29/2013
        [executions] => 1
      )

    [4] => Array
      (
        [day] => 1/30/2013
        [executions] => 3
      )

    [5] => Array
      (
        [day] => 2/8/2013
        [executions] => 1
      )

   [6] => Array
      (
        [day] => 2/11/2013
        [executions] => 3
      )

)
```

I am building a graph of this data, and basically it represents the last 30 days. The problem is I don't get the missing days, i.e. when there was no executions from the query. I am looking to fill in these missing days with PHP, simple set the `day` to the correct date, and `executions` to `0`. Thus the result array should contain 30 elements, assuming start is `1/18/2013` and end is today `2/17/2013`.

Any idea of the best algorithm to accomplish this in PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
$start = '1/18/2013';
$end = '2/17/2013';

$range = new DatePeriod(
  DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $start),
  new DateInterval('P1D'),
  DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $end));

$filler = array();

foreach($range as $date)
  $filler[] = array(
    'day'      => $date->format('m/d/Y'),
    'execution' => 0,
  };

$array += $filler;
```

Comment: Getting error: `Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DatePeriod::__construct(): This constructor accepts either (DateTime, DateInterval, int) OR (DateTime, DateInterval, DateTime) OR (string) as arguments.`

Comment: Ok, here is the result, the array is not sorted properly though, it simply appended the missing days to end of the array. http://pastebin.com/7YkCLzHC

Comment: Within the foreach loop, check if the date exists in the original array, and skip assigning the filler entry if it is...

Comment: Yeah, though how do I check if the current `$date` exists in the original? I can't simply use `in_array()` since the array keys are indexes, and the values are arrays().

Comment: You know that this would be much easier if you made the `day` date string the key and `execution` the value. You wouldn't need so many foreach loops then

Answer (score 2):

Loop through each date using DateTime:

```
$start = new DateTime('2013-01-18');
$end = new DateTime('2013-02-17');
while ($start <= $end)
{
    $current_date = $start->format('m/d/Y');
    // Right here look in your array and see if that date exists
    // and do whatever you need to do if it does/does not
    $start->modify("+1 day");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this:

```
$startDate = new DateTime ( "-30 days" );
$dateItter = new DatePeriod ( 
    $startDate,
    new DateInterval ('P1D'),
    30  
);

$original = array (
    array ( 
        'days' => '02/16/2013',
        'executions' => 5
    )   
);

$result = array (); 

foreach ( $dateItter as $date )
{
    $executions = 0;

    foreach ( $original as $item ) { 
        if ( $item['days'] == $date->format ( 'm/d/Y' ) ) 
            $executions = $item['executions'];
    }   

    $result[] = array (
        "day" => $date->format ( 'm/d/Y' ),
        "executions" => $executions
    );  
}

var_dump ( $result );
```

It is slow for large amount of data but for 30 items will be ok!